# Nosetests not seeing test classes that unittest discover does

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, nose, python-unittest

I have what I can only consider a very odd problem with the way nosetests identifies classes that are valid tests classes.

I'm initialising a test class as a generic `type` with specific inheritance from a base tests class by using:

```
def random_test_class(n):
    print "Generating %d random test cases..." % n
    def make_test(genre, ss, ps):
        return lambda self: self.compose(genre, ss, ps)
    return type('TestEverything', (TestBase,),
                { 'test_%d' % i: make_test(genre, ss, ps)
                  for (i, (genre, ss, ps)) in zip(xrange(n), generate_settings())
                })
```

and then initialising the class proper with

```
class TestEverything(random_test_class(100)):
    pass
```

Now, when I call my standard testing framework with `python -m unittest discover`, the testing is all very happy and it sees the `TestEverything` class as a test class defining 100 test methods (`test_1`, `test_2`, etc...). However, if I use `nosetests ./ -m "test_*"` it refuses to see `TestEverything` as a valid test class, and doesn't run any of its test methods.

How can I solve this? I really need the `xunit` output framework that `nosetests` provide, but I would very much like to avoid going through all the metaclass faff that is required to properly initialise a class with a specific test metaclass.

Answer (score 1):

When deciding whether or not to include methods in tests, Nose checks the *name of the function* that implements the method rather than the attribute name. Change you `make_test` so that the test created has a name that Nose will pick up.

```
def make_test(genre, ss, ps):
    def test(self):
        self.compose(genre, ss, ps)
    return test
```

This will match the regular expression you give in your question. `test_*` matches any name that has `test` in it followed by any number of underscores.

Note that if you wanted the functions to have different names you could pass the index to `make_test` and set `test.__name__`:

```
def make_test(i, genre, ss, ps):
    def test(self):
        self.compose(genre, ss, ps)
    test.__name__ = 'test_%d' % i
    return test
```